# Analysis of algorithm for permutation generation

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, analysis

I've been trying to get around for the analysis of this C++ program for permutation generation. I know in the algorithm that the time complexity is O(n*n!) and O(n) because it requires it to print a permutation. Can someone further explain the analysis of the implementation below?

```
// permutation generator
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation, std::sort

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3};

  std::sort (myints,myints+3);

  do {
    std::cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';
  } while ( std::next_permutation(myints,myints+3) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you see O(n\*n!)? ("n!", literally: [factorial of n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) would be really terrible but I cannot find it in your sample.) [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Complexity) has O(N*log(N)). [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation#Complexity) has at most N/2 swaps.

Comment: Have a look at the [Possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation#Possible_implementation)  of `std::next_permutation()`. Though, the mathematical definition of permutation usually might use factorials, there's no such terrible construct in this implementation - instead a simple loop with checks and swaps - which is "smelling" like O(N).

Comment: @scheff: std::next_permutation is amortized O(1) if there are no duplicates in the vector. But it is O(n) to print the permutation, as OP says. There are `n!` permutations, so the whole process takes O(n * n!)

Comment: @rici Sigh. That's true. I forgot to consider the `do while` loop...